# Did Yoshihiro Togashi make an agreement that in the event of his passing, nobody would be allowed to complete Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I've recently heard a rumor suggesting that Yoshihiro Togashi has some form of agreement that, in the event of his passing, nobody else would be allowed to complete 'Hunter x Hunter.'

Has anyone else come across this claim? Additionally, I've been curious about Togashi's intentions for the continuation of 'Hunter x Hunter' if he were unable to finish it. Does anyone have credible sources or official statements from Togashi or his publishers regarding the future of the series?

Comment: As far as I searched in Japanese, [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jump_henshubu/status/1607029146630103041) is the last announcement regarding hxh. It just says it stops 'weekly releases' and other forms of publishing is being planned. I don't really understand what it means, given how the series went all these years...